# protoc file not found error in generating for dart

Tags: flutter, dart, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-dart

i wanted to generate the protos for dart by

```
protoc --proto_path=pb/proto --dart_out=lib/api/grpc/pb/gen --plugin=path/to/plugin/.pub-cachce/bin pb/proto/*.proto
```

but it says

```
path/to/project/pb/proto/user.proto: File not found.
path/to/project/pb/proto/product.proto: File not found.
badget.proto:5:1: Import "path/to/project/pb/proto/user.proto" was not found or had errors.
badget.proto:6:1: Import "path/to/project/pb/proto/product.proto" was not found or had errors.
badget.proto:24:3: "packagename.pb.user.Actor" is not defined.
badget.proto:37:3: "packagename.pb.product.Product" is not defined.
badget.proto:65:22: "packagename.pb.user.Actor" is not defined.
```

!!!i actieved the plugin before that
!!! the path to project is not compelete path (its started by the the path configured in setting)

protos=>
badgte.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package packagename.pb.badget;

import "path/to/project/pb/proto/user.proto";
import "path/to/project/pb/proto/product.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

blah blah blah;
```

user.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package packagename.pb.user;

blah blah blah;
```

product.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package packagename.pb.product;

blah blah blah;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to rearrange things so that the path specified in `--proto_path` is the parent directory of the paths you use for `import`s.

Paths in `import` statements are relative to what you've provided with `--proto_path`. So for `--proto_path=pb/proto` and the statement `import "path/to/project/pb/proto/user.proto"`, `protoc` will be looking for a file `"pb/proto/path/to/project/pb/proto/user.proto"` which is probably not what you intend.

You might want to consider something like `protoc --proto_path=path/to/project`, so that your `import` statements are shorter/more portable:

```
import "pb/proto/user.proto";
```

Also, check [this](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/3028#issuecomment-511016932) to see if it applies to your situation.

Finally, there are some typos in your post (".pub-cachce", "badget" vs. "badgte", etc.) so you may want to check on those as well, in case the typos are present in your actual code.

Comment: tnks for the point , by reconfiguring the path in fixed